# React chakra ui Global Theme fontFamily

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm trying to make the app change the fontfamily by breakpoint values, so i have this:

```
export const breakpoints = {
  sm: "600px",
  lg: "800px",
}

export const fonts = {
  heading: "SF pro",
  global: {
    html: {
      sm: "SF pro",
      lg: "Roboto"
    }
  }
}

export const theme = extendTheme({
  fontSizes,
  breakpoints,
  semanticTokens,
  colors,
  fonts,
  components,
})
```

i don't understand why this not working, and the documentation don't help anything =/
anyone already solve that problem?

Comment: Is this the actual code? The theme needs to be passed to the `ThemeProvider` as per https://v0.chakra-ui.com/getting-started

Comment: its a part of them, i pass the themeprovider and all the chakra works, i only have a problem with fontFamily, i need to set that in a global thing, now i'm doing in every component, to avoid that i want to set in a globaltheme, but i dont find any way to do that